# Passwords from completed contracts/work on equipment

Tags: business

I am the IT person working at a small business in Oklahoma and have been trying to get access to our network and firewall.

I found out that the last IT company (Texas Based) that did the firewall install 5 years ago will not give the owners the passwords to the equipment. They state proprietary information is a stake and they will fix things as needed, for a fee of course.

My company owns the firewalls. All contracts with the other IT company expired 3 years ago. They keep offering to do as we need for a fee. and they seem to have threatened that if we take over our systems they will sue, disrupt, disable or otherwise "Let our equipment crash" but never going as far as saying it.

I know as long as I have physical access to the equipment I can "Take Ownership" and the manufacturer of the firewall has even provided information on doing just that, but there is always a risk when you force things and I would just like the company to do what they are supposed to.

What laws are out there on this and how can I force the issue without rebuilding the firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Advice on specific cases is explicitly out of scope on this site. It sounds as if you need a real lawyer, fast. Getting one should be a minor expense compared to either paying or disrupting your firewall.

For the general case:

- An IT contractor may provide software as a service ([SAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)). The software installed and maintained belongs to the contractor, the customer only **buys the use** of the software. There would be an ongoing contractual relationship, usually paid per month or so.
- An IT contractor may configure software for a customer. The customer **buys the work of the contractor** made to make the software run somewhere. The contract would be finished and paid at some time, with the work turned over and accepted. At that point, the contractor should turn over all credentials.
- There may be a sequence of contracts as per the second bullet point, with the contractor holding credentials between jobs for future use based on a framework contract.

A contract may specify one or the other, or it may be badly written.